# FailedToParse: Password must be URL Encoded for mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to connect to `MongoDB v4.2.X` using below command and getting the error.

> FailedToParse: Password must be URL Encoded for mongodb:// URL: mongodb://user:user@123@localhost:27017/my-employees?authSource=admin
>   try 'mongo --help' for more information

The URL = `mongodb://user:user@123@localhost:27017/my-employees?authSource=admin`

Comment: I think you are writing it in a wrong way. Try this way:
`mongodb+srv://user:password@localhost:27017/my-employees?authSource=admin
`

Comment: Hey, still the same error.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If your password is `user@123`, you're using a special character (a delimeter) in your connection URI. According to the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#examples):

> If the username or password includes the at sign @, colon :, slash /,
> or the percent sign % character, use percent encoding.

Percent encoding is another name for URL encoding mentioned in your error.

`@` will be `%40` in percent-encoding, and your connection string would be:

`mongodb://user:user%40123@localhost:27017/my-employees?authSource=admin`

You can also use [this online tool](https://www.url-encode-decode.com/) to URL-encode your username/password.